# How to map Parent field to child object field using Dozer

Tags: mapping, dozer

I am using Dozer to map my objects A to B

```
Class A {
int indicatorA;
List<A> listA;
// get set methods...
}

Class B{
int indicatorB;
List<B> listB;
// get set methods...
}
```

I am tring to map A to B and I would like to set parent indicatorA value to all childs inside listB
Example :

```
A parentA = new A();    // with indicatorA = 10
A child1A = new A();    // indicatorA value has not set
A child2A = new A();    // indicatorA value has not set
parentA.getListA.add(child1A);
parentA.getListA.add(child2A);
```

After mapping, I would like see object B like this

B parentB // with indicatorB = 10
**and parentB.listB with 2 objects child1B and chld2B with indicatorB value set to 10**

How to write a custom converter or any easy way to do this ?
Any help is greatly appreciated..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need a CustomConverter implementation for this, as values cannot be set inside elements of a List through direct mapping.

The Dozer XML needs a simple configuration tag, referencing the CustomConverter class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
          http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
  <configuration>
    <custom-converters>
        <converter type="somepackage.MyConverter" >
            <class-a>somepackage.A</class-a>
            <class-b>somepackage.B</class-b>
        </converter>
    </custom-converters>     
  </configuration>
</mappings>
```

And this is the CustomConverter:

```
public class MyConverter implements CustomConverter {
    public Object convert(Object destination, Object source, Class destClass, Class sourceClass){
         if (source == null) {
              return null;
            }
            B dest = null;
            if (source instanceof A) {
                // check to see if the object already exists
                if (destination == null) {
                  dest = new B();
                } else {
                  dest = (B) destination;
                }

              //dest is your parentB instance

              //setting indicatorB value in parentB
                dest.setIndicatorB(((A) source).getIndicatorA()); 

              //creating child instances of B
                B child1B = new B();
                B child2B = new B();  

              //setting indicatorB values to the child instances as well
                child1B.setIndicatorB(((A) source).getIndicatorA());                
                child2B.setIndicatorB(((A) source).getIndicatorA()); 

              //adding child Bs to parentB list
                List<B> listOfBs = new ArrayList<B>(); 
                listOfBs.add(child1B);
                listOfBs.add(child2B);
                dest.setListB(listOfBs);
                return dest;
            }
            return null;        
    }
}
```

If the number of childAs are known only at runtime you can use a loop in the CustomConverter to create a corresponding number of childBs.